# Spring boot validation not validating @RequestBody

Tags: spring-boot, validation

Validation does not kick in when posting to RestController. Very simple application setup with springboot-starter-validation added to build.gradle. Code is written in Groovy.

Entitiy to be validated:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
class Event extends Base {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotBlank
    String name
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService

    @PostMapping("/api/event")
    Event createEvent(@Valid @RequestBody Event event) {
        eventService.save(event)
    }
}
```

When posting simple json: `{"name": ""}`to the endpoint "/api/event" I would expect that Spring would throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` but the entity is saved with `""` as a value for `name`. Adding BindingResult as parameter to `createEvent` yield 0 binding errors.

I must be missing something. But I can't spot what it is. Can you? :)

Comment: In my trial-and-error frenzy I tried that - even though it should not be necessary... The `@Validated` annotation is validation groups... It did not do the trick.. :)

Comment: Yes - as I have written in the top of the post :)

Comment: @EnableWebMvc ? (which is equivalent to DIY/disables "auto configuration" ..in spring-boot!)

Comment: I have not explicitely stated @EnableWebMvc as I have springboot-starter-web as a dependecy as well... (And I would rather go with autoconfiguration all the way - or so is my thougt, but....)

Comment: no, bud, absolutely "cannot reproduce"/works like charm: https://github.com/xerx593/vaildation-groovy-demo ([starter used](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=groovy&platformVersion=2.6.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=validation-demo&name=validation-demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.validation-demo&dependencies=web,validation,h2,data-jpa))

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with spring-boot-starter-validation in the Maven environment and it is working fine. On giving `{"name": ""}` it throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-01-12T02:20:21.059+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": ......,
    "message": "Validation failed for object='event'. Error count: 1",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotBlank.event.name",
                "NotBlank.name",
                "NotBlank.java.lang.String",
                "NotBlank"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "event.name",
                        "name"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "name",
                    "code": "name"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be blank",
            "objectName": "event",
            "field": "name",
            "rejectedValue": "",
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotBlank"
        }
    ],
    "path": "/api/event"
}
```

Comment: Exact same source code?

Comment: The controller is exactly the same. In entity, you have a parent class, but I declared an id variable in the Event class itself for the primary key and it doesn't have a parent class.

Comment: Tried using a non-entity class for the sake of debugging. Added a `EventFormObject` with a single attribute `String name` with `@NotBlank` annotation. Result is the same - no validation kicks in...